# How to make sql queries run faster in excel?

Tags: sql, excel, excel-2007, vba

In order to optimize a report i changed all the pivot tables present in it to sql queries since using pivot is not an effective way to code. However to my surprise , sql queries are taking more time than pivot . Are there any standard ways to optimize sql queries or connection  to make my tool run faster?

Comment: I guess it all depends on your database engine and the way you store your data

Comment: @AndreyAdamovich I am using an ADO connection.

Comment: But that's just an abstract connection API. Which database are you connecting to (Access, MS SQL, Oracle)? I would try executing your queries directly in that database first to see if they perform badly.

Comment: I am not surprised: pivot tables are a very efficient in-memory solution. An equivalent data base solution would be an in-memory OLAP cube or PowerView

Comment: Are you sure it's executing the SQL which is taking the time and not outputting the results?

Answer (score 0):

Given you have the option to use legally in production and freedom to try out few robust DBMS, then you could do test your data on each of them.

This will allow you to rate the peformance of each connection type and DBMS. You may not have to reinvent the wheel as many developers out there have tried most DML syntaxes on these DBMS. Have shot questions on most relevant areas.

To make the selection process faster, you could use most crucial/most high demand tables/data and do the query that would nag every possible table to output some 'super' data...

Avaialbility of **support** for a chosen DMBS is very important to guide you through. Specially if you have in current/future plan to migrate/integrate into certain platforms/ external BI tools. e.g. We were involved in a migration of our real time reporting engine from Excel/Access to Oracle & Microstrategy. It was hectic at that point as not many have proven resources were on the shelf for us to reach out.

It all depends on how scalable you design your database, access freaquency of data (wtheather it's real time/just running batch processing one/two times a day/week)

Just to add a bit on **compatibility**, Excel and MySQL server 2008 seem to work in a more friendly matter. Perhaps they are supported by the same *house*